# Ocaml's named parameters

Tags: ocaml, currying, named-parameters

Trying to understand Ocaml's mechanism for named parameters. I understand the basics, but the [doc](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual006.html#htoc37) shows an example like this:

```
# let f ~x ~y = x - y;;
val f : x:int -> y:int -> int = <fun>

# let x = 3 and y = 2 in f ~x ~y;;
- : int = 1
```

What exactly is going on when only the tilde is used in application? Is it just shorthand for `~x:x`, similar to definitions? If so, can someone explain why this:

```
# ListLabels.fold_left;;
- : f:('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> init:'a -> 'b list -> 'a = <fun>

# let add = (+) and i = 0 
in ListLabels.fold_left ~add ~i [1;2;3];;
```

produces

```
- : f:((add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'a) ->
   int -> add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'a) ->
init:(add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'a) -> 'a = <fun>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The man says 
"beware that functions like ListLabels.fold_left whose result type is a type variable will never be considered as totally applied."

Here is what happens in your example. Beware it's a bit involved.

```
# ListLabels.fold_left;;
- : f:('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> init:'a -> 'b list -> 'a = <fun>
```

is just the classic use: `ListLabels.fold_left` taks 3 arguments, namely a function labeled `f`, an initializer `init` and a list.

Now, in

```
let add = (+) and i = 0 
in ListLabels.fold_left ~add ~i [1;2;3];;
```

the application `ListLabels.fold_left ~add ~i [1;2;3]` is considered incomplete (as the man says). That means that `` `ListLabels.fold_left `` receives first its unamed argument, `[1;2;3]` and returns a function of type `f:('a -> int -> 'a) -> init:'a -> 'a`. Let us call this function foo.

Since you're giving two named arguments, labeled `add` and `i`, the type `'a` is inferred to be a functional type, of type `add:'c -> ~i:'d -> 'e`.

Based on the type of the *variables* `add` and `i`, the type `'c` must be `int -> int -> int`, and `'d` must be `int`.

Replacing those values in the type `'a`, we derive that the type `'a` is `add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'e`.
And replacing this in the type of foo (I'm glad there is copy-pasting ;-), its type is

```
f:((add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'e)
    -> int
    -> (add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'e))
-> init:(add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'e)
-> (add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'e)
```

Removing unecessary parentheses, and alpha converting (i.e. renaming) `'e` to `'a`, we get

```
f:((add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'a)
    -> int
    -> add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'a)
-> init:(add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'a)
-> add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'a
```

That is the type of foo. But remember that you are passing two arguments to foo, labeled `~add` and `~i`. So the value you get at the end is not of type `add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'a` but indeed of type `'a`. And the whole type of your example is, as returned by the compiler,

```
f:((add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'a)
    -> int
    -> add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'a)
-> init:(add:(int -> int -> int) -> i:int -> 'a)
-> 'a
```

Comment: Wow - what a mess! It actually does make sense though, thank you so much!